# Node title inside layout (Layout Discovery + Field Layout)

Tags: theming, entities

Just tried the new core modules Layout Discovery and Field Layout and I want to render the title of a node between two fields.
Without these modules, node's title can be rendered between other fields very simple by using inside `node.twig.html` something like:

```
{{ content.field_image }}
{{ label }}
{{ content.body }}
```

But when I try to use `{{ label }}` inside the registered layout template, nothing gets rendered. Can somebody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get variables inside layouts due to this bug https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2861840
Drupal 8.5 fixed the problem.
Now, inside mytheme.theme if I put this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_layout(&$variables) {
  $request     = \Drupal::request();
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $title       = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());
   $variables['node_title'] = $title;
}
```

I'm able to use `{{ node_title }}` inside layouts.